# How to Stop Breaking Bootstrap Row on Smaller Device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on making a site responsive.At the Header section I am using Bootstrap Row. It is working good on relatively large display but when i go to smaller device,it is breaking to two lines.Below is my code and screen shot of my problem.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="visible-xs col-xs-1"><span class="#w3-button #w3-teal #w3-xlarge mbtn" onclick="w3_open()">☰</span>   </div>

    <div class="visible-xs col-xs-5" style="margin-bottom:5px !important;"> 
       <img src="http://mycustomsite.tryfcomet.com/image/catalog/ranga_woods2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="RangaWoods" Title="RangaWoods">
    </div>  

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div id="top-links" class="nav pull-right hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total" title="<?php echo $text_wishlist; ?>"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></span></a></li>
            <li><a  href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>" title="<?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?>"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>" title="<?php echo $text_account; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_account; ?></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- row-->
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: try adding `style={box-sizing: 'border-box'}` to the parent div, after the class.
`<div class="row" style={box-sizing: 'border-box'}>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my problem setting to col-xs-6 col-xs-5 col-xs-1 padding-left to zero which was by default 15px

Comment: did you try `<div class="row" style={box-sizing: 'border-box'}>` on the parent component? that should keep everything inside the parent view which should rectify the situation as well.

Comment: Awesome.  Please vote up and accept the answer since it worked.